# How is trueskill used when the rating is negative

Tags: python

So I'm using this trueskill implementation built in python https://trueskill.org

And here is my code

```
def start():
    trueskill.TrueSkill(backend='scipy').cdf
    r1 = Rating()
    r2 = Rating()

    t1 = [r1]
    t2 = [r2]

    (new_r1,), (new_r2,) = rate([t1, t2], ranks=[1, 2])
    print(new_r1.exposure)
    print(new_r2.exposure)
    print(new_r1.mu - 3*new_r1.sigma)
    print(new_r2.mu - 3*new_r2.sigma)
```

And the output:

```
7.881405258020575
-0.910258781977749
7.881405258020575
-0.910258781977749
```

Is anyone here experienced enough with this algorithm able to tell me how a rating of -0.9 is useful to be put onto a leaderboard?

I'm using what the official website says to do:
[image]

I don't get it. I'm supposed to tell people that their rank is -0.9???

Comment: As the quoted text says, the formula and thus the result estimate *skill* not *rank*. So someone with a skill of ``-0.9`` has a lower rank than someone with a skill of ``7.88``, for example.

Comment: Yeah but I guess there is no way of quantifying this then like with the ELO system? With ELO you can display someone's MMR publicly. Any idea of how I could determine a single number that could help players know if they are better than someone else?